# Examples of real functions, satisfying the following conditions, or provide counter-examples

Tags: real-analysis

1. $g \circ f$ is injective, but $g$ is not injective.
2. $g \circ f$ is surjective, but $g$ is not surjective.
3. $g \circ f$ is surjective, but $f$ is not surjective.
4. $f, g$ are not injective, but $g \circ f$ is injective.

I am having trouble with 1,2,3 as I am not sure how to prove them.

For 4) I was thinking about doing a contra-positive example (if $g \circ f$ is not injective then $f$ and $g$ are injective. This contradicts because we know that injectivity holds through composition but I am not sure if that is the right way to do that question)

Thank you for your help in advance and if you need extra definitions let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. $$
   f:x\in\{0\}\rightarrow 0\in\mathbb R\\
   g:x\in\mathbb R\rightarrow 0\in \mathbb R
   $$
   then $f$ and $g\circ f:x\in\{0\}\rightarrow 0\in\mathbb R$ are injective because domain is a singleton but $g$ isn't injective.
2. There aren't such $g$: let $f:X\rightarrow Y, g:Y\rightarrow Z$ such that $g\circ f$ is surjective then for every $z\in Z$ exists $x\in X$ such that $z=(g\circ f)(x)=g[f(x)]$ then let $y=f(x)$ we have $z=g(y)$ and $g$ is necessary surjective.
3. $$
   f:x\in\mathbb R\rightarrow 0\in\mathbb R\\
   g:x\in\mathbb R\rightarrow 0\in \{0\}
   $$
   then $g$ and $g\circ f:x\in\mathbb R\rightarrow 0\in\{0\}$ are surjective because codomain is a singleton but $f$ isn't surjective.
4. $f$ must be always injective: let $f:X\rightarrow Y, g:Y\rightarrow Z$ such that $g\circ f$ is injective then for every $x, x'\in X$ such that $f(x)=f(x')$ we have trivially that $g[f(x)]=g[f(x')]$. This implies that $x=x'$ because $g\circ f$ is injective then also $f$ must be injective.